# Unable to find MQX 4.2.0.1 / 4.2.0.2

Tags: nxp-microcontroller, mqx

I am trying to download patches 4.2.0.1 or 4.2.0.2 for NXP MQX 4.2.0 operating system.
However, it seems that all links have been removed by NXP and that now they make available only MQX 5 (upon payment).

I am particularly interested in this bug fix:

MQX-5540
- Added checking of the heap low address and the heap high address against the memory address 0x20000000 to see whether the global variables reside on that address and issue warning to the user.
- Affects all BSPs.

I would be very grateful if someone has a link to or can make available sources for 4.2.0.1 / 4.2.0.2 or at least the piece of code for bug fix MQX-5540.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this question, it seems the asker posted this to the NXP community forum and received a link to the 4.2.0.2 patch:

https://freescale.jiveon.com/thread/474697

Comment: Thank you, I missed that answer. Sorry for cross-posting without waiting some time.